Angular - Can't reference a controller twice?
I'm new to Angular, and I know I don't understand some concepts.  What's the concept that I'm missing?
I wrote a simple Angular program that restricts what characters can be entered into a prompt.  I want digits but I don't want anything else.  We're entering an integer here.
So, here is PayMethod.js:
var mod = angular.module('EntryApp', []);
mod.controller('EntryController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.keydown = function ($event) {
        if ($event.keyCode >= 48 && $event.keyCode <= 57) {
            // digits
        } else {
            // any other keys - prevent
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});

The Angular code doesn't change for this test.
Here's my index.html document:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/PayMethod.js"></script>
    <div>
        <h2>Example 29</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Why does the first and second entry use the keydown, but the third ignores it?</p>
            <div ng-app="EntryApp" ng-controller="EntryController">
                First entry: <input id="FirstEntry" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" />
                <br />
                Second entry: <input id="SecondEntry" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" />
            </div>
            <div ng-app="EntryApp" ng-controller="EntryController">
                <br />
                Third entry: <input id="ThirdEntry" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

In this case, the program permits only digits for the first and second entries, but it permits all characters for the third entry.
If I take out the div tags in-between the second and third entries, like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/PayMethod.js"></script>
    <div>
        <h2>Example 29</h2>
        <div>
            <p>Now all three work.</p>
            <div ng-app="EntryApp" ng-controller="EntryController">
                First entry: <input id="FirstEntry" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" />
                <br />
                Second entry: <input id="SecondEntry" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" />
                <br />
                Third entry: <input id="ThirdEntry" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Now, the program only permits digits for all three entries.  Can I only reference a controller once?  Or am I missing an elephant in the room?

I think you're defining two root controllers.  (You can only have 1 per page.) You're using the old version of Angular here methinks.  You should start with "Angular" (new) instead of "AngularJS" (old).

Thank you, that was the "elephant in the room".  I find it so difficult starting out knowing the difference  between a site that says it is "Angular", but is really "AngularJS" and a site that is truly "Angular".  Now I know to look for the "script" that directs to "AngularJS".
